# Git push para em "Total"

Tags: git

Eu tenho alguns projetos hospedados no azure e uso o git para o versionamento, todos sempre funcionaram bem porém de uma hora para outra um desses repositórios começou a dar problema e não finaliza o push (porém apenas comigo, com outras pessoas do projeto funciona normalmente. Já deletei o projeto e baixei novamente desde o zero, mas não funcionou.

Acontecem dois tipos de erro:

Erro 1 (o processamento para no "Total" e não acontece nada, nem termina nem da erro):

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 1167, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1146/1146), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1115/1115), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1115/1115), 292.52 MiB | 16.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 1115 (delta 549), reused 76 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Erro 2 (passa desse ponto do total com um erro 503):

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 1167, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1146/1146), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1115/1115), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1115/1115), 292.52 MiB | 16.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 1115 (delta 549), reused 76 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Já segui várias coisas que poderiam dar certo, mas nenhum funcionou, aumentei o `http.postBuffer` tanto globalmente quanto apenas para o projeto, nada resolveu.

Tentei também baixar o Fork e dar o push pela interface gráfica, mesmo assim não mostrou nenhum erro, ficou quase uma hora processando o push e cancelou.

E tenho 3 commits locais aqui que não podem ser perdidos, pois envolveram muito trabalho, alguem sabe como posso sair disso?

---

**EDIT**
Print com git status e o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: por causa do erro 503 eu diria que está tendo problemas de rede (a mensagem já mostra isso *"unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet"*). No momento de finalizar o comando falhou, isso acontece comigo às vezes no gitlab, seja por muitas conexões ou outro problema de rede.

Comment: O estranho é que todos os outros repositórios funcionam normalmente, na mesma rede, mesmo computador, e esse erro 5003 é muito dificil acontecer, 90% das vezes ele só para no "Total" mesmo, mas vou tentar em outra rede assim que possivel

Comment: Testei agora em outra rede, da na mesma, fica parado no "Total".

Answer (score 0):

Atualize o seu git!

A maioria dos erros de conexão, quando outras pessoas continuam a fazer push, por exemplo, se deve a falta de atualização do git.

No Windows uma boa ideia é instalar o git pelo [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), um gerenciador de pacotes, usando:

```
choco install git.install -y
```

- Sempre use o Terminal/Prompt em modo Administrativo
- O pacote git.install é otimizado para Windows, apesar de existir o pacote "git", recomendo sempre o *git.install* nesse [SO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operativo)
- Parâmetro *-y* vai aceitar automáticamente todas perguntas durante a instalação

Depois é só você checar de tempos em tempos se existem atualizações para o pacote ou quando der um erro desse tempo verifique se existe um novo!

```
choco upgrade git.install
```

[image: Imagem do terminal executando o comando acima]

Ao executar esse comando ele verifica se existe uma nova versão, mostra a versão que está instalada e a última, conforme imagem acima.
Se usar o paâmetro *-y*, a atualização será executada.

Para apenas verificar se existe atualização para o pacote, use:

```
choco outdated
```

Todos os pacotes instalados pelo *chocolatey* serão verificados.

Comment: Ainda nada, desinstalei meu git antigo e instalei via chocolatey, ocorreu tudo certo e instalou a versão `2.30.2.windows.1`, porém ainda na mesma, fica travado em "Total", desconfio que possa ser algum arquivo dando problema na hora de subir para o azure, o problema é descobrir qual.

Comment: Por favor, faça print do erro, print com git status e mande aqui

Comment: Outro ponto de teste: você está em uma rede wi-fi/cabo? Tentou em uma rede completamente diferente? Talvez por 3G/4G? Eu já tive problema com operadora e o gir.

Comment: Editei a questão adicionando o print. Ainda não fiz o teste no 3G, mas testei logado na VPN do meu trabalho e deslogado, nenhum dos dois modos funcionou, utilizo o wifi e apenas esse repositório da erro, ao todo tenho mais outros vários repositórios que usam git ou svn, e todos os outros funcionam, mas vou testar no 3G assim que possivel.

Comment: Qual o máximo de tempo que você já esperou para ver se o push segue em frente? Tente esperar para saber o que acontece...
Você não perdeu as permissões nessa pasta?

Comment: Aguardei em torno de 30 a 40 minutos, ai desisti, pois mesmo que fosse algum arquivo muito grande (coisa que não é), é muito tempo.
As permissões estão OK, já tirei e coloquei de novo, loguei com a conta responsável pelo repositório, nenhum funcionou, está bem estranho.

Comment: Testei no 3G agora, mesmo problema.